# Eclipse Mars 2 JRE Missing Jars

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I recently migrated to a new Windows 10 computer.
In Eclipse, click "Window"-"Preferences". Navigate to Jave-Installed JREs. I have one JRE installed/defined: jre1.8.0_181 "Standard VM". The location is correct (C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181"

Click "Edit" and I see the correct Directory, correct JRE name, but in the JRE system libraries box, it is ONLY showing C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib\rt.jar

ll of my other jars (e.g. jce.jar) are missing. I have tried to "Add External" and it APPEARS to have worked, click "Finish" and "Apply"/"OK", but when I go back in, they are gone.  And my project will not compile because it is dependent on javax.crypto.

All I've been able to do so far is to modify my PROJECT's build path and add all of the standard JCE jar-files there as "external jars".

What can I do to get this to work the correct way?

I have tried to use the JDK's jce (by defining the directory to the JDK root) and that includes rt.jar and then all of the jars located in ...jre\lib\ext but not the others in ...jre\lib

I'm at a loss. Please help.

Comment: What do you have in here? C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\

Comment: I do have the 32-bit version of Java 1.8.0_181 jre installed. So C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181 with the lib subdirectory and all of the 32-bit jar files...

Comment: Are there other libs in this folder "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib\" - I take it thats supposed to be the 65 bit install?  If there aren't, possibly reinstall it?

Comment: Yes, the 64-bit install. There's two lib files in the directory: jawt.lib and jvm.lib. This is a fresh install.

Comment: IMHO - looks like your installation somehow got screwed up.  Personally, as a java developer I dont ever install anything java related in program files just because the space in the name can be problematic (more troublesome) if you even need to run something manually from the cli.  Might I suggest you re-download the JDK and when installing be sure to change the path to C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181 or C:\jdk1.8.0_181 - also watch out as when it tries to install the JRE, you can specify the path as you did with the JDK, but it seems it then just puts it in your specified path as well as the Prog Folder